# Extract my timeline posts from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to extract my posts, via Graph API from facebook. I used some basic code snippets but they don't work. I can not get my feed even in the Graph Explorer. It always says that I don;t have the permission and I have to submit my App for review and provide a video tutorial on how I use the extracted posts.

But I want to extract just my posts, I don't care for anybody elses. Do I seriously need FB App review to do that?

This is what I get with my token from my app:
[image]

user/posts requires additional contract signing:
[image]

Comment: please add your code and/or api calls and detailed debug information including the exact error messages.

Comment: @luschn: This is a general question. Can I extract my posts via Graph API without going through the whole approval process for my App? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/me/posts` with your own App, with your User Token and authorize with the `user_posts` permission. This works without any approval from Facebook - for your account and your App only, of course. I just tested if it still works in the Graph API Explorer and it did: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/108138225915615/?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts&version=v5.0

Comment: The "user_posts" requires additional contract signing and is not available by default. I need to make a video for this permission. This is my problem. The app that I can create in the API v5 is void of any permissions and I can not get even my profile ... This was different in previous APIs, but now this ... See image in post edit.

Comment: you only need this for your own account, right? in that case, you do not need review. the error message suggests that you just did not authorize the user_posts permission. although, i tried with an older (but unapproved) app, i might try with a fresh one.

Comment: Yes, I just want to extract my own timeline and maybe a page that I own. I don't need anybody else. Could you please expand on the "authorize the user_posts permission" ? I don't remember doing that before, and I don't think I did it now, so maybe that's the cause.

Comment: just add it to the permissions in the api explorer on the right side and hit the "get access token" button. for pages it is different though, you would need to authorize with manage_pages and use a page token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: The only permission that I can add, is email.

Comment: interesting, i can add everything in all apps, no matter if they are reviewed or not...maybe you need to write to the facebook support then?